# Calculate distance to other node of same type

Tags: java, recursion, set, nodes, distance

I'm writing a program that calculates how far 2 nodes (persons in this example) are from each other.

```
public class Person() {
    private Set<Person> persons;

    public int calculateDistanceTo(Person person) {
        // how to do this
    }
```

I tried using recursion. But that causes the program to go on endlessly.

Here's the (not working code).

```
public int calculateDistanceTo(Person person, int count) {

    if (persons.contains(person)) return 0;

    for (Person p : persons) {
        count += p.calculateDistanceTo(p, ++count);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: does your `Person` class implement `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: i've made the class implement Comparable<Persion> so it implements the mehod equals(Person o)

Comment: Comparable and equals aren't related. With Comparable you need to implement compareTo.  With equals, you will still need hashCode to be implemented. verifying whether `contains` method is working properly

Comment: Ok, i've just overridden the equals and hashCode methods (using intelij wizard). But this doesn't solve anyting. containts() seems to work fine

Comment: should your code be `count += persoon.calculateDistanceTo(p, ++count);`?

Comment: Why do you calculate the distance from `p` to `p` in the statement in the for-loop. Shouldn't it be something like `count += p.calculateDistanceTo(person, ++count);`?

Comment: So you basically need to implement a graph traversal algorithm like Breadth First Search or Depth First search for this time of calculation to work. Your current approach doesn't make sense in this problem.

Comment: hi Quinus, have you got a good answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(public class Person() is not syntactically correct in Java)*

Firstly, let's see what's the following loop doing:

```
for (Person p : persons) {
    count += p.calculateDistanceTo(p, ++count);
}
```

Take the following relationship as an example:
[image]

In the above case, let 1 be p1, and 2 be p2, etc. P1 and P4 are not linked, so when you do:

```
p1.calculateDistanceTo(p4, 0);
```

The recursion stack would be:

```
calculateDistanceTo(2,1)
    calculateDistanceTo(1,2)
        calculateDistanceTo(2,3)
        … infinite
```

That's why you go into an infinite loop.

To correct that:
1) You need to add a flag to a person if a person has been visited
2) The for loop should be used to determine the shortest distance from the person visited to the target person.

So essentially, it is a depth first search with some comparison to give the shortest path. (Of course, to find the shortest path in a uni-distance, we should use breadth first search. But I derived depth first search based on your given solution)

So an example would be:

```
public class Person {
private Set<Person> friends;

int id;
boolean visited = false;

public Person(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    friends = new HashSet<>();
}

public Set<Person> getFriends() {
    return friends;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return id + "";
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return ((Person) o).id == this.id;
}

public int calculateDistanceTo(Person person) {
    this.visited = true;
    if (friends.contains(person)) return 0;

    int shortestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;
    for (Person friend : friends) {
        if (!friend.visited) {
            int dist = friend.calculateDistanceTo(person);
            if (dist < shortestDistance) {// finding the shortest distance
                shortestDistance = dist;
            }
        }
    }

    return 1 + shortestDistance;
}

static Person p1 = new Person(1);
static Person p2 = new Person(2);
static Person p3 = new Person(3);
static Person p4 = new Person(4);
static Person p5 = new Person(5);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5));

    p1.getFriends().add(p2);
    p1.getFriends().add(p3);

    p2.getFriends().add(p1);
    p2.getFriends().add(p3);

    p3.getFriends().add(p1);
    p3.getFriends().add(p2);
    p3.getFriends().add(p5);

    p5.getFriends().add(p3);

    int dist = p1.calculateDistanceTo(p4);
    System.out.println(dist); // 1073741824 means no relation

    for (Person p : persons) p.visited = false;// clear flag

    dist = p1.calculateDistanceTo(p2);
    System.out.println(dist); // 0

    for (Person p : persons) p.visited = false;// clear flag

    dist = p1.calculateDistanceTo(p5);
    System.out.println(dist); // 1
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BOND's answer is working, but there is a big Issue in implementation: The internal state of the objects will be modified during calculation. In a multi-threaded environment this will lead to unexpected behaviour. So here is my solution for this.

First the class Person (I stored a name and called the Set 'neighbours':

```
public class Person {
    private final Set<Person> neighbours = new HashSet<>();
    private final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void addNeighbour(Person p)
    {
        neighbours.add(p);
        p.neighbours.add(this);
    }
    public int calculateDistanceTo(Person p)
    {
        return calculateDistanceTo(p, 0, Collections.emptySet());
    }
    private int calculateDistanceTo(Person person, int count, Set<Person> tried)
    {
        if (neighbours.contains(person))
            return count;
        Set<Person> nextTry = new HashSet<>(tried);
        nextTry.add(this);
        return neighbours.stream()
                .filter(p -> !nextTry.contains(p))
                .mapToInt(p -> p.calculateDistanceTo(person, count+1, nextTry))
                .filter(i -> i>=0)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(-1);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "name=" + name + '}';
    }
}
```

I am creating a set of persons which I have already tried and give this set into the calculateDistanceTo method. And if two Persons are not connected, my method will return -1. So my main() method will look the following:

```
public static void main(String ... args)
{
    Person p1 = new Person("Anton");
    Person p2 = new Person("Berta");
    Person p3 = new Person("Charlie");
    Person p4 = new Person("Dora");
    Person p5 = new Person("Emil");

    p1.addNeighbour(p2);
    p1.addNeighbour(p3);

    p2.addNeighbour(p3);

    p3.addNeighbour(p5);
    System.out.println("Distance from Anton to Dora = "+p1.calculateDistanceTo(p4)); // -1
    System.out.println("Distance from Anton to Berta = "+p1.calculateDistanceTo(p2)); // 0
    System.out.println("Distance from Anton to Emil = "+p1.calculateDistanceTo(p5)); // 1
}
```

**Edit** As you see, it is not neccessary to implement equals() and hashCode() because we only use the references here.